# Проблема с привязкой WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, build

Имеется некая структура, например `NotMyStruct`. Прямого доступа к коду структуры нету. Имеется класс `MyClass`, в котором находится экземпляр этой структуры под именем `valStruct`. В струкутре есть поле вида

```
uint? Value { get; set; } = null;
```

Так же имеется `UserControl` в кором находится `ListBox` с привязкой к `DataConext`. В этот `ListBox` из `ObservableCollection` через привязку добавляются объекты `myClass`. Это всё работает.

Далее. Через `DataTemplate` описываю примерно такой стиль стиль:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyClass}">
    <Grid>
        <Slider Value="{Binding valStruct.Value, 
        Converter={StaticResource DoubleToUintConverter}, 
        Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Ps. Конвертер ошибок не выдает. По сути просто конвертирует через `System.Convert`

Проблема в том, что значение `Value` при так и остаётся `null` при движении слайдера. 
Как правильно осуществить такую привязку?
**UPD**

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(uint?))]
public class DoubleToUintConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToUInt32(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите конвертер

Comment: @PavelMayorov добавил

Comment: `valStruct` - судя по имени, это не паблик проперти? В таком случае забайндить корректно не получится.

Comment: @icebat `valStruct` 'это экземпляр структуры `NotMyStruct`, Он может быть спокойно паблик. Пролема в том, что `NotMyStruct` запечатанная структура.и реализовать `OnPropertyChanged()` внутри не является возможным, а сделать как то иначе я не знаю как.

Comment: Может тогда просто завернуть `valStruct.Value` в отдельную пропертю MyClass-а с поддержкой PropertyChanged и делать все операции с Value через нее?

Comment: @icebat Если бы не около 40 полей, то так бы и сделал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблем в вашем коде множество.

Для начала, `NotMyStruct` — типично модельная структура данных, которая, разумеется, не реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Поэтому ловить изменения в этой структуре ваш код не сможет, лишь отправлять изменения из UI в неё.

Затем, у вас конвертер конвертирует в неправильную сторону. Он должен конвертировать из `uint?` в `double`, а у вас наоборот. Исправляем конвертер:

```
public class NullableUintToDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)((uint?)value ?? 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (uint)(double)value;
    }
}
```

Дальше. Ваш `Slider` выдаёт значения от 0 до 1, поскольку не выставлен `Maximum`. При округлении до целого получается чистый ноль, поэтому `Binding` записывает значение 0 в свойство. Чтобы починить это, поставим максимум в `uint.MaxValue`:

```
<Slider Value="{Binding valStruct.Value, 
            Converter={StaticResource NullableUintToDoubleConverter}, 
            Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Minimum="0" Maximum="4294967295"/>
```

Затем, большая проблема: мутабельная структура! Мутабельные структуры — зло. Значения не проваливаются в структуру через binding к `valStruct.Value`, и вот почему.

Как происходит обращение к `valStruct.Value`? Сначала у класса `MyClass`, являющегося `DataContext`'ом, ищется публичное свойство `valStruct`, и получается его значение через геттер. Поскольку `valStruct` есть структура, **вы получаете копию значения**! Когда из этой копии читается значение `Value`, проблем нет: `Value` в копии такое же, как и в оригинале. Но когда через тот же `Binding` значение `Value` **записывается**, то модифицируется при этом лишь копия `valStruct`, а не оригинал!

Как это исправить? Например, вы можете заврапить это свойство:

```
public NotMyStruct valStruct { get; set; }

public uint? valStructValueBindable
{
    get { return valStruct.Value; }
    set { valStruct = new NotMyStruct() { Value = value }; }
}
```

(обратите внимание, что в сеттере мы создали свойство заново!)

Или так:

```
NotMyStruct valStruct;

public uint? valStructValueBindable
{
    get { return valStruct.Value; }
    set { valStruct.Value = value; }
}
```

(в этом случае вы пишете прямо в структуру, а не в её копию).

При этом ваш XAML получает вид

```
<Slider Value="{Binding valStructValueBindable, 
            Converter={StaticResource NullableUintToDoubleConverter}, 
            Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Minimum="0" Maximum="4294967295"/>
```

Вуаля, всё работает.

Comment: Спасибо. Только подмечу, что по умолчанию у меня `Maximum` был равен 100, так как слайдер кастомный.

Comment: @BwehaaFox: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, помогло.

Comment: Как понимаю враппить придётся каждое поле в структуре? Или может есть какая нить специализированная библиотека или подпрограмма на подобии [KindOfMagic](https://kindofmagic.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @BwehaaFox: Боюсь, что да. Если полей много, возможно, имеет смысл написать кодогенератор, чтобы не вручную.